# On the relation $\Delta U = -W$ for electric work

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

My text writes $\Delta U = − W$ with $W$ the electric work and $U$ the electrical potential energy. I tried to verify this relation for a simple case. I considered bringing close to another two positive charges initially at infinite distance. As work is defined as $W = \mathbf{F} ⋅ d\mathbf{s}$ as the displacement and the force applied have the same direction the work is positive. Regarding the variation of electrical potential energy $\Delta U = U_f - U_i$ taking $U_i(\infty) = 0$ we have a positive $\Delta U$ too, so the relation $\Delta U = − W$ seems not correct. What's the fault in my reasoning (if there's one)?

Comment: The W in that expression is the work done *by the electric field*, which is negative when two like charges are brought close to each other, because the electric forces are directed away from each other and hence in the opposite direction as the motion. It seems you are assuming that that W is the work done by other objects on the charges to push them together, which is not the correct interpretation.

Comment: @march Please consider entering this comment as an answer.

Comment: why is there a different between $F_{elec}$ and $F_{external}$?

Comment: @BobD Questions like this are usually duplicates, which is why I just made a comment. I looked for a duplicate, but I’m really bad at finding them, so I figured I’d leave that for someone else but in the meantime help

Comment: @march  Related question&answers: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559642/how-is-electric-potential-related-to-potential-energy-and-work-in-electrostatics?rq=1

Comment: @march I think your comment was directed at Chemomechanics not me. My comment was directed at the OP

Comment: @BobD Oops! Yep! Sorry.